# Remove app from SharePoint with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, 2013, app

I have deployed an app to SharePoint 2013, but something went wrong during deployment. Now I cannot remove or redeploy this app.

**Can I force remove this app with powershell or STSADM**, like you can do with broken lists? If yes, then how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have solution of that app then just retract that app. It will remove whole app from your site.

or

follow this link : http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161233.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Go to SharePoint classic view in site contents to see remove option for apps.